# Run only one mocha test file on change with gulp

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, gulp

I have a standard gulp test watcher and runner for my Node.js/mocha setup;

```
gulp.task('mocha', function() {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

  return gulp.src(['./test/**/*.js'], {read: false})
    .pipe(mocha({
      recursive: true, 
      reporter: 'list', 
      ui: 'bdd'
    })).on('error', gutil.log); 
});

gulp.task('tests', function() {
  gulp.watch(sources.concat(tests), ['mocha']); 
});
```

I'm wondering how to adapt my watch task (and the other) to only send to mocha the test that has changed - so that I don't have to wait 20 seconds for a hundred tests to run.

I've tried this with fgulp-newer and gulp-cached, but no luck.

I'm looking here for an answer or for a pseudo-algorithm for a gulp plugin I could then write for this purpose :)

Comment: Maybe you already know that but you can add on your mocha test 
`it.only()`
on the test that you are editing. And when gulp will launch your tests. Only this one will be executed.

Comment: Didn't know this, thanks! This covers some of what I need. If you put it as an answer, I can accept it.
But I also need something like `describe.only()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use in your mocha test `it.only()` to run only one test

`describe.only()` is available too

Comment: And coming back a while after the question, also describe.skip and it.skip are useful.